# Is there any way to get expanded critical range or higher critical multipliers?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, critical-hit

Is there currently any way to get an expanded critical range (allowing a critical hit on a 19 on the die, or even lower) or a higher critical multiplier (at least x3) on *weapon* attacks?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is one way to get an expanded critical range - the Champion Fighter's Improved Critical feature.

> **Improved Critical**
>
> Beginning
> when
> you
> choose
> this
> archetype
> at
> 3rd
> level,
> your
> weapon
> attacks
> score
> a
> critical
> hit
> on
> a
> roll
> of
> 19
> or
> 20.

Which later becomes Superior Critical:

> **Superior Critical**
>
> Starting
> at
> 15th
> level,
> your
> weapon
> attacks
> score
> a
> critical
> hit
> on
> a
> roll
> of
> 18–20.

The Hexblade's Curse grants them Improved Critical against a single target (for...some reason).

There is no way to get a higher critical multiplier. However, there are 2 methods of adding the weapon's damage die an extra time on a critical. This is analogous to a x3 multiplier, or x4 if combined, but only multiplies weapon damage, not any other source of damage. The half-orc's Savage Attacks feature:

> ***Savage
> Attacks.***
> When
> you
> score
> a
> critical
> hit
> with
> a
> melee
> weapon
> attack,
> you
> can
> roll
> one
> of
> the
> weapon’s
> damage
> dice
> one
> additional
> time
> and
> add
> it
> to
> the
> extra
> damage
> of
> the
> critical
> hit.

And the Barbarian's Brutal Critical feature:

> **Brutal Critical**
>
> Beginning
> at
> 9th
> level,
> you
> can
> roll
> one
> additional
> weapon
> damage
> die
> when
> determining
> the
> extra
> damage
> for
> a
> critical
> hit
> with
> a
> melee
> attack.
> This
> increases
> to
> two
> additional
> dice
> at
> 13th
> level
> and
> three
> additional
> dice
> at
> 17th
> level.

Meaning that a half-orc Barbarian 17/Champion Fighter 3 gets a crit on a 19-20, and deals the weapon's damage die 6 times over on crits. Note that [this doesn't work quite as well with weapons that do 2d6 damage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46574/15469).

Comment: Don’t forget the Piercer feat. “When you score a critical hit that deals piercing damage to a creature, you can roll one additional damage die when determining the extra piercing damage the target takes.” Source: Tasha's Cauldron of Everything p. 80

Answer (score 0):

In theory, your GM might allow you to stack the expanded critical abilities if you multi-classed 15 levels into Champion fighter and 5 levels into Hexblade warlock. A GM might allow the improved criticals to stack (17-20), and if you get the right enchantment on your weapons it could go up. Granted, that is all the GM's choice; talk to them about it.

Comment: @GOW Could you back this up with some citations? On what basis might the GM do these things? If it's pure fiat, on what basis do you pick these numbers out in particular?

Comment: @rpgstar Requesting citation is fair, but advising that we stick to RAW or only the core rulebooks as much as possible is not correct advice: we don't require those things.