# Enhancement Question For My Hexadin

Tags: dnd-5e, paladin, hexblade

This is a bit of a min-max question, I built a level 12 half-drow hexadin:

- 8 oath of vengeance paladin
- 4 hexblade warlock with pact of the blade

My feats are: GWM, Elven Accuracy (CHA) and Lucky, going for max crit chance build with a greataxe.

I have 2 questions:

1. Which fighting style would you take as a paladin? I don't know if I should take Blessed Warrior with *guidance* and *spare the dying* or Defense for the extra 1 to AC
2. I can start with an uncommon magical item, what would you take? Assuming it might also be rare if I can convince my DM, what rare item would you take?

The campaign is a homebrew version of the *Curse Of Strahd*, made for up to level 20, we mainly face 1 single very powerful opponent, sometimes they are 2 or 3.

Comment: Hi there! I think the question as it stands is too opinion-based for this site; also, you are asking two questions at once, which is not allowed. If you could ask a narrower question focused on a specific ability or game feature (e.g. "How do I make my character really good at doing XYZ?"), that would be better. Please visit the [Help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about what kinds of questions are on-topic here.

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per question, unless they are so close like two sides of the same coin. Ad 1) please clearly define what criteria are for answer to be good or bad. You said you are going for max crit but then you consider +1 to AC so your goals are unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Because most of what you talk about seems to be related to improving your damage output and combat, my impression is your primary focus is survivability, damage output and combat. I will answer in that light.

1. **Defense**. *Guidance* is an extremely useful cantrip, strong enough to create complaints that it [warps how the game is being played](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56055/casting-guidance-cantrip-for-every-roll), but normally you do not make that many skill checks in combat. Even if you had a grappler on the team, you still do not want to sacrifice your action in combat to cast it, when you could be doing full attacks to hopefully score a critical. You also probably want to reserve your concentration for *hex*. *Spare the dying* likewise is solid, and is more useful in combat, but it also costs an action. Hopefully you have a cleric with you who can cast *healing word* as a bonus action instead, which will put the character not only to stable, but back in action. On the other hand, especially if you wear heavy armor and have a high AC, [every point to AC counts](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/176346/how-do-i-explain-to-an-add-player-that-items-that-increase-armor-class-in-dd-5/176363#176363), it is always on and does not consume your actions or concentration.
2. **Magic Greataxe**. For a melee combat character little else is going to be as important as a magic weapon. In a higher level campaign many of your opponents have resistance to non-magical damage (were-creatures may even be immune, but also demons, devils, greater undead and so on). A magic weapon does full damage nearly all of the time, and a +1 one is something few DMs have an issue with granting. That is such a big improvement over half damage that little can measure up to it. If you can choose, a *greataxe of warning* might be even better, initiative and no surprise for the whole team is very strong. Likewise, if you can get your DM to give you a rare item, a *[flame tongue greataxe](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/198508/which-magic-weapon-deals-the-most-damage)* is your best weapon option for damage -- unfortunately, as far as I know there is no uncommon or rare weapon that [improves your critical range](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97756/is-there-any-way-to-get-expanded-critical-range-or-higher-critical-multipliers).

If you have free choice, going by sane [magic item prices](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?424243-Sane-Magic-Item-Prices), which is unofficially pricing items based on their power, for uncommon you could also try other uncommon items are overpowered for their rarity, for example *winged boots* or a *broom of flying* (which might fit thematically into Ravenloft but they would not be a great fit for a melee build), or a *helm of telepathy*.

For rare, if the DM allows it [Cloak of Displacement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4605-cloak-of-displacement), giving disadvantage to nearly all attacks against you, or *Helm of Teleportation* are powerful choices that work with your build. Necklace of Prayer Beads might be even more powerful with the right rolls, but if I were the DM to grant it, I would pick one with low-impact beads. Few DMs would have an issue with granting a +1 Armor. A [*sun blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4774-sun-blade) would be extremely good against all the undead in general, and due to the sunlight, vampire spawn snd Strahd in particular, but for adventure reasons I do not want to get into here, the DM is unlikely to hand out one of those. At least I as your DM surely would not.